# Phonegap/Cordova file-transfer not uploading Error_code 1 Even Static Parameter won't send

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am having problem with the Cordova file-transfer script.

It varies from device to device, on my Lg g3 it won't upload anything above a certain size around 700kb, but older device will upload larger files around 1.5mb, any thing above it says error_code 1, image not found. So it does uploads, if the images are small. 
I checked the backend, when it fails to upload, even the parameters are empty.

My code is with below(i combined it with a multi-image picker as well)

```
     function selectimages() {  
         window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {




        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {



            var imageURI results[i];
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = "myTestUpload.jpg";
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            var params = new Object();
    options.params = params;


    var ft = new FileTransfer();



     alert(options.params.dev_id); 



    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI('http://api.test.com/setImage'), win, fail,
        options);


        }






        function win(r) {

    alert("Response = " + r.response);

}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    alert("upload error source " + error.source);
    alert("upload error target " + error.target);
}

    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }
);
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the core of the problem. Because when targetwidth/height is set to 0/default, it is set to the Original size, and the images are initially put in the App's memory before it is transfered out. And that uses up the App's memory, and then it crashes the plugin but not the app for some reason, and that removes the images and all parameters, hence the file not found Error_code 1.